# How to populate an array with user input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

hello am i doing this correctly im trying to add the user input to an array

```
while (repeat !== "n")
  {
    var Student = prompt("Enter Student Name: ");
    var StudentArr = new Array(Student);
    var mark = parseInt( prompt("Enter Student Mark: ") );
    var markArr = new Array(mark);
    var repeat = prompt ("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
  }
```

Comment: you didn't add values to array .this create a array named student name.use  array.push("values");

Comment: repeat is undefined when function start

Comment: could u please show me what u mean in more detail i sort of understand what u mean but im really new to java and am not sure how to use push thankyou tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrays need to be defined outside the loop.

```
var repeat, studentArr = [], markArr = [];
while (repeat !== 'n' && repeat !== 'N'){
    studentArr.push(prompt("Enter Student Name: "));
    markArr.push(prompt("Enter Student Mark: "));
    repeat = prompt ("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
}
console.log('studentArr, markArr',studentArr, markArr);
```

Result:

studentArr, markArr ["Dan", "Bill"] ["A", "B"]

Answer (score 1):

First create arrays which exist outside of the scope of your while loop. If you don't do this, all changes to your array will be lost whenever the loop repeats itself.

When declaring a new array, you pass an integer as `n` into `new Array(n)`. This determines how many array slots to allocate for your array. So `new Array(5)` would create an array with 5 slots. If you leave `n` empty, then you will get an empty array.

```
var markArr = new Array(); //you can also do var markArr = [];
var StudentArr = new Array();

while (repeat !== "n")
  {
    var Student = prompt("Enter Student Name: ");
    //use the array push() method to add items to your array
    var Student.push(Student);
    var mark = parseInt( prompt("Enter Student Mark: ") );
    markArr.push(mark);
    var repeat = prompt ("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
  }
```